# iOS upload image php return empty

Tags: php, ios, image, image-uploading

In `php`:

The `Upload` method:

```
    /**
     * ### this function is file upload
     * auto file name  and file path
     * @param $FILES  File to file
     * @param string $A
     * @param string $B
     * @return bool|string
     */
    protected function Upload($FILES,$A="",$B=""){
        $ReturnFILE = array();
        $FILES = array_keys($FILES);
        foreach ($FILES as $K => $V) {
            $FlodName = "Updata/".date("Y-m-d");
            if(!is_dir($FlodName)){
                mkdir($FlodName,777,true);
            }
            if ($_FILES[$FILES[$K]]["error"] > 0){
                return false;
            }
            $tempEXT = strstr($_FILES[$FILES[$K]]["name"],".");
            $FileName = date("YmdHis").UUID().$tempEXT;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$FILES[$K]]["tmp_name"],"{$FlodName}/" . $FileName);
            $http_type = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
            $FileName =$http_type.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$FlodName."/".$FileName;
            $ReturnFILE[] = $FileName;
        }
        return $ReturnFILE;
    }
```

The `ImageEdit` method use `Upload` method to upload the iOS app bypassed image:

```
 public function ImgEdit()
 {

    $imgs=$this->Upload($_FILES);
    var_dump($imgs); 
    // success 
    if (!empty($imgs)){
        echo 1;
        $datas = [
            'code' => 200,
            'message' => "修改成功",
            'data' =>$imgs
        ];
        echo json_encode($datas);
    } else {  // fail
        echo 2;
        $datas = [
            'code' => 0,
            'message' => "修改失败",
            'data' => ""
        ];
        echo json_encode($datas);
    }
}
```

In the iOS app, I use this method to upload my image:

```
- (void)networkUploadHeadImage:(UIImage *)image {

    UIImage *img = image;
    NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

    NSDictionary * param1 = @{
                              @"imgFile":dataObj
                              };
    AFHTTPSessionManager * session = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    session.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"application/xml",@"text/json",@"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain",@"multipart/form-data",nil];

    //拼接地址
    NSString *url = @"http://103.71.178.145:8088/Home/Aboutus/ImgEdit";

    [session POST:url parameters:param1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

        UIImage *img = image; // response
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"imgFile" fileName:@"imgFile.png"mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"success+%@", responseObject);

        //保存
        NSString *result_url_str = responseObject[@"data"];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"fail");

    }];
}
```

The result is:

if I use iOS the method to upload my image:

The database we can see the uploaded image, it success, but in `ImageEdit` method, the `$imgs` is empty:

```
var_dump($imgs);  the `$imgs` is empty.
```

And my iOS app execute : `NSLog(@"fail");`

If I use the html form submit:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="Insert" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I will get the `$imgs`, it have the path of the uploaded image.

Why I use `- (void)networkUploadHeadImage:(UIImage *)image` get nothing about `$imgs` ?

---

**EDIT**

If I use KK's answer:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,url] parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            if (image) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) name:@"imagename" fileName:@"Image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }

        }error:nil];

       AFURLSessionManager * urlSessionmanager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

        urlSessionmanager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [urlSessionmanager
                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                      progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

                      }
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {

                              NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
                          } else {
                           // successfully uploaded
                          }
                      }];

        [uploadTask resume];
```

I will print the error information:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://103.71.178.145:8088/Home/Aboutus/ImgEdit } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
>       "Content-Length" = 239;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf8";
>       Date = "Mon, 17 Apr 2017 11:18:20 GMT";
>       Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=a5n20to0r0ahk554ppa79jfp56; path=/";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.33, ASP.NET";
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://103.71.178.145:8088/Home/Aboutus/ImgEdit, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<0d0a3231 6e676e67 32617272 61792831 29207b0a 20205b30 5d3d3e0a 20207374 72696e67 28363329 20226874 74703a2f 2f313033 2e37312e 3137382e 3134353a 38303838 2f557064 6174612f 32303137 2d30342d 31372f32 30313730 34313731 39313832 302e6a70 67220a7d 0a317b22 636f6465 223a3230 302c226d 65737361 6765223a 225c7534 6665655c 75363533 395c7536 3231305c 75353239 66222c22 64617461 223a5b22 68747470 3a5c2f5c 2f313033 2e37312e 3137382e 3134353a 38303838 5c2f5570 64617461 5c2f3230 31372d30 342d3137 5c2f3230 31373034 31373139 31383230 2e6a7067 225d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

But if I uploads like the KK's updated method like this:

```
UIImage *img = image;
NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

NSString *url = @"http://103.71.178.145:8088/Home/Aboutus/ImgEdit";

NSDictionary * param1 = @{
                          @"imgFile":dataObj
                          };


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:param1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    if (image) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) name:@"imagename" fileName:@"Image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }

}error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager * urlSessionmanager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

urlSessionmanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [urlSessionmanager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {

                      NSLog(@"err=%@", error);
                  } else {
                      // successfully uploaded
                      NSLog(@"success= %@, === %@", response, responseObject);
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Although I success, but did not get the return url, the PHP did not return the URL(the image's path) to me.

See my log:

> 2017-04-17 19:34:50.058 uploadImgTool[73016:16061592] success=  { URL: http://103.71.178.145:8088/Home/Aboutus/ImgEdit } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
>       "Content-Length" = 232;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf8";
>       Date = "Mon, 17 Apr 2017 11:34:24 GMT";
>       Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=1qqv4nnp5gf5o8nqcuhve12ds2; path=/";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.33, ASP.NET";
>   } }, === <0d0a6172 72617928 3129207b 0a20205b 305d3d3e 0a202073 7472696e 67283633 29202268 7474703a 2f2f3130 332e3731 2e313738 2e313435 3a383038 382f5570 64617461 2f323031 372d3034 2d31372f 32303137 30343137 31393334 32342e6a 7067220a 7d0a317b 22636f64 65223a32 30302c22 6d657373 61676522 3a225c75 34666565 5c753635 33395c75 36323130 5c753532 3966222c 22646174 61223a5b 22687474 703a5c2f 5c2f3130 332e3731 2e313738 2e313435 3a383038 385c2f55 70646174 615c2f32 3031372d 30342d31 375c2f32 30313730 34313731 39333432 342e6a70 67225d7d>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upload image using below my code snippet .

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,url] parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            if (image) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) name:@"imagename" fileName:@"Image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }

        }error:nil];

       AFURLSessionManager * urlSessionmanager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    urlSessionmanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [urlSessionmanager
                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                      progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

                      }
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {


                          } else {
                           // successfully uploaded
                          }
                      }];

        [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: see my EDIT, brother.

Comment: Thanks, my friend , now I success, but I did not get the URL(image path), you see the `php` code. I want give me the return path.

Comment: check restriction in server side .as per that check  code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141880/discussion-between-three-blocks-and-kkrocks).

Comment: add your response which you are got it